# How to get contributors for opensource search engine

Tags: full-text-search, search-engine

We are a company developing opensource search engine.

It's hosted in github (https://github.com/fastcatgroup/fastcatsearch)

I think we need contributor globaly, but don't know where to start.

Have any good idea or strategies?

Giving it to Apache or Jboss community is good idea?

Thanks.

Comment: I think you may misunderstand how the open source community and lifecycle behave.  It is up to you to provide a compelling solution to people's problems in a way that encourages them to contribute back enhancements that are of value.

Comment: Ok, Caskey. I understand that it's first to provide a value to a people.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's importance that the open-source solution is which many people need, and solution must be stable. Here's an simple strategy.

1. Make a stable opensource solution
2. Write a detail manuals online.
3. Promote an opensource using SNS
4. If online group getting larger, start to make a offline group.